# How do I add multiple Card Views in Material for iOS?

Tags: cosmicmind

I am trying to add multiple card views through storyboard. I link the up to code with IBOutlet and add the title view and detail view. Once i run the app and go to the CardViews, the app crashes giving me the "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" The first CardView (grammarCard) works fine but the second does not (vocabCard).

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
```

import Material

class StudyViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var vocabCard: CardView!

@IBOutlet weak var grammarCard: CardView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Grammar Card Title
    let gTitleLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    gTitleLabel.text = "Grammar"
    gTitleLabel.textColor = MaterialColor.deepPurple.darken1
    grammarCard.titleLabel = gTitleLabel
    // Grammar Card Detail
    let detailLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    detailLabel.text = "Learn"
    detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    grammarCard.detailView = detailLabel
    // Start button
    let button: FlatButton = FlatButton()
    button.pulseColor = MaterialColor.deepPurple.lighten1

    button.pulseScale = false
    button.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(MaterialColor.deepPurple.darken1, forState: .Normal)
    // Adding Buttons

    grammarCard.rightButtons = [button]
    //THIS ONE IS FINE

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Vocab Card Title
    let vTitleLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    vTitleLabel.text = "Vocabulary"
    vTitleLabel.textColor = MaterialColor.deepPurple.darken1

    vocabCard.titleLabel = vTitleLabel // Here the issue pops up
    // Vocab Card Detail
    let vdetailLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    vdetailLabel.text = "Learn the words of "
    vdetailLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    vocabCard.detailView = vdetailLabel // Here the issue pops up
    // Start button
    let vbutton: FlatButton = FlatButton()
    vbutton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.deepPurple.lighten1

    vbutton.pulseScale = false
    vbutton.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
    vbutton.setTitleColor(MaterialColor.deepPurple.darken1, forState: .Normal)
    // Adding Buttons

    vocabCard.rightButtons = [vbutton]


}
```

Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

I am not seeing an issue in the code, so it is most likely with the setup in storyboards. So we added an example in [1.39.9](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/1.39.9) that uses two CardViews and storyboards. You can find this in the Examples/Storyboards directory.

All the best!